# android camera YUV response to color

Tags: android, camera, yuv, exposure

I try too calibrate my YUV conversion with the screen(24 pouces) of my PC. And i foud out that the YUV response is changing.
For example if a look at the screen the widows logo,meanly bleu i got the correct bleu YUV conversion.
But if i open another window with a lot of white the YUV conversion is very bad. There is nearly no bleu responding to the bleu part.
The same problem when i modify the angle of the camera. It is automatycly changing the YUV response.

If there is more or less white color on screen the color response (YUV) is automaticly modified.

It is possible to avoid this automatic change and if some one could explain why this happened.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the answer to said that it is nearly impossible to calibrate YUV to RGB. By setting exposureLock,whitebalancelock and exposurecompensation once at the begining change nothing to help calibration.

Conclusion. It loock nearly impossible to calibrate the RGB color value From YUV. Exposure and ligth change all the time and there are no info about the change.

If someone got the solution i take ;))